# Toolbar is not showing in Activites

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar

I'm pretty new at programming, especially in Android Studio. So I am making an app for my term paper. I wanted to make it possible to navigate through a Navigation Drawer, which can be opened by a Button in a Toolbar. The Toolbar isn't showing up, but when I click at the point in the app, where the Button should be, the Drawer opens up.

Here is my main activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorBack">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="@color/colorBack">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/MainPic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/pic_9974" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/SpacerTop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/rectangle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/SpacerBot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="258dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/rectangle2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcomeHead"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/welcome_head"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTop"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SpacerBot" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcomeText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/welcome_text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTop"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/welcomeHead" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_layout"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.appbm">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/TestTheme"
        android:background="@color/colorBack">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here my Styles:

```
<resources>
    <style name="TestTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorTop</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorTopDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And here a cut out of my main activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
```

Unfortunately I couldn't help myself in other posts.

I hope someone can help me.

Dome K.

Comment: Its showing up I tested Your xml its showing me toolbar

Comment: @Dome K. check my answer and try that it will help you...

Comment: Problem in your xml 
It's a constraint layout and you didn't set all other layout below to the toolbar.
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your MainActivity

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.bringToFront();
```

Comment: Problem was in XML. need to correct the constraints rather than use workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your **`main activity xml`** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

// customize your toolbar

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_dashboard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_dashboard"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_dashboard_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

in **`style.xml`** :

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    // for NoActionBar
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
// for AppBar
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
// for Toolbar
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

and in **java class** use this for toolbar only :

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

in **manifest** file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.appbm">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" // change here
        android:background="@color/colorBack">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I tested the simpler idea, Visakh had and it worked. But also thank you very much too for your quick help! :)